# How to intentionally minimize the system entropy

Tags: random, yubikey

My question might seem counter-intuitive at first, as most of the time people want to do the opposite (i.e., increase entropy). I have a few USB devices that act as random number generators -- namely, *Yubikey 5* and *Ledger Nano S*. The former is described as a cryptographically-secure Pseudo RNG while the latter is claimed to be True RNG.

What I want to do is to intentionally *minimize* the system entropy as much as possible and then run the RNG diagnostics utilities (e.g., *ent*, *dieharder*, etc) on each of the above devices. Ideally, I'd want to completely eliminate entropy outside of these two devices as to ensure that whatever I get is produced internally (on board), but that is not possible as far as I understand. Any suggestions/feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: hmm, why would you need to disable everything else? There's some tool that reads the RNG of the tokens, right? and then feeds it to the system RNG maybe? Just read the raw output from the token and run _ent_ or _dieharder_ on that output.

Comment: Seems you want to talk to these devices directly instead of going through the kernel/system-wide random facility. The kernel will give you random looking data even for bad entropy sources, the diagnostic tools won't help you much there.